# Browsing to PDF causes the PDF to be downloaded instead of displayed

Tags: sharepoint, pdf, browser

I have two servers with virtually identical setups (the second that is working has been around longer than the other).  For my newer server when I just put an address to a PDF in the browser it launches a download dialog.  If I put the same address (just changing the server name) in the browser to my older server it displays in the browser just fine.  There is no difference between the files themselves.  The issue is I want to display these pdfs in an iframe on a page and the same thing is happening with the iframe (the new server launches a download instead of the pdf just showing in the frame).

Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: I've looked and the MIME types appear to be identically setup on the two machines (application/pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I started looking into SP 2010 as being the cause I found that there is a default setting for all new 2010 sites that causes this issue.  The following blog post had the most complete information on the subject:

http://nerdtastictips.blogspot.com/2010/08/sp2010-forces-users-to-save-pdfs.html

Answer (score 0):

Please indicate web server your are using
Initial suggestion may be this has to do with MIME-TYPE setup

Comment: you could try adding mime type  application/octet-stream against pdf

Comment: thanks for the idea, tried and unfortunately it seems have no effect.  I switched it back to application/pdf (hoping that would jar something into working) and no effect.

Comment: Ok in some research it appears that is actually related to it being a sharepoint site.  Somehow it's altering how the file is being sent.

Comment: OK yes followed your lead and I guess you found this too http://nerdtastictips.blogspot.com/2010/08/sp2010-forces-users-to-save-pdfs.html